# Google Chrome Package App: How to add icon on notification area?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, hosted-app

Is there a way to add an Icon on notification area / system tray / system icon for my google chrome package app? Can it also listen when the icon on notification area is click (left or right)?

If this question is already posted, please provide me the answer link.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "notification area", and on what platform? What kind of icon? Do you really mean hosted app, or perhaps packaged?

Comment: I mean packaged app on windows platform

Comment: Repeat: what is "notification area"? Please edit the question to clarify it.

Comment: "notification area" is also known as system tray / system icon area

Answer (score 0):

The notification Area is the area in Windows by the clock:

[image: Notification Area]

Did you get it to work @Jeff Robert Dagala?

I haven't found exactly what you were looking for, however it seems to be possible since the google hangouts app is placed in this area.

Maybe a side track, but here is information on how to pop up notifications:

Notifications API:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications

Example app:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/world-clock/lhfiglpmnendbchimlikaeachppfonmm

Lots of samples:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples